# How to reset an absolute positioned element to the top left of the screen

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute, hamburger-menu

I´m currently trying to build a hamburger menu without JS, which should drop down from top to bottom when clicking it.
The Burgermenu is at the top right of the screen and each time I want to drop down the navigation, it simply doesn´t drop down centered, but at the very right of the screen, aligned with the left border of the hamburger div.

My css looks like so:

```
@media (max-width: 1099px) {
  #menuToggle {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  #menuToggle input {
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 32px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px;
    left: -5px;

    cursor: pointer;

    opacity: 0; /* hide this */
    z-index: 2; /* and place it over the hamburger */
  }

  /*
   * hamburger
   */
  #menuToggle span {
    display: block;
    width: 33px;
    height: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    position: relative;

    background: black;
    border-radius: 3px;

    z-index: 1;

    transform-origin: 4px 0px;

    transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1),
      background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1), opacity 0.55s ease;
  }

   .
   . lots of animation
   . 

  /*
   * The Navmenu that has to drop down
   */
  #nav-menu {
    position: absolute;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    background: orange;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vh;
  }
}
```

html:

```
<div id="menuToggle">
        <input type="checkbox" />

        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>

        <nav id="nav-menu">
          <li>Functionality</li>

          <li>Run a node</li>

          <li>About DFINITY</li>

          <li>Contact formula</li>
        </nav>
 </div>
```

How it looks (arrow indicates how I want it to be):

[image: Example]

As you can imagine I want it to be at the top left corner of the screen. So I can

```
transform: translate(0, -100%);
```

When the checkbox isnt cheked and

```
transform: none;
```

when it´s checked.

I always thought, that absolute positioning takes the element from the flow of the page and resets it, but it somehow sits right underneath my hamburger.
Transform-origin to 0 0 also doesn´t work.
What did I understand wrong here?

(Dont worry ill change the color)

Comment: Could you explain what is to happen at higher viewport widths? I realised your code has no styling above 1099px. And where is your CSS selector for the input being checked?

Comment: You need to have everything under one element (could be body) and position everything in relation to that. It is important that the nav-menu remains a sibling of the input else the input being checked can't influence the nav-menu. But you need nothing to have a position until you get up to body (or some element that covers the viewport at least) otherwise you can't position the drop down where you want it.

Comment: @Kosh, yes I understand that the trialled use of transform-origin wouldn't work - it was the use of transform that seemed to me to be fine but you said was misunderstood.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your menu is positioned relative to its parent div `#menuToggle`. Just put `#navMenu` outside of it, i.e. as a direct child inside the body element, and make sure to set:

```
#navMenu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    ...
}
```

You may have to set the body to `position: relative` as well.

Comment: Hi, if nav-menu is put outside that div how can the input being clicked influence it?

Comment: @AHaworth If it has to stay inside, remove position:relative from #menuToggle